# Matlab Function Input/Output Optimization: Cells or Matrix?

Tags: matlab, optimization, time

I am trying to determine the most time-efficient method of passing data to/from a function, given a set of differently sized matricies that need to be passed.

Due to the requirements of the program, the user will be defining a number of inputs (any amount from 1-10), and function 1 will generate a set of matricies for each input. These matricies are Nx6, where the number of rows "N" is defined by the user for each individual case (usually around 200-400).

Once I have these matricies, I need to pass *ALL* of them into a single function, and return an output based on the results of a simulation. Since these are all differently sized matricies, I have been storing them all together in a Cell, and just shipping them back and forth as needed.

Ex: (simplified for convenience and readability)

```
clc
clear
%Inputs
numInputs = 10;
NumRows = [3 4 51 2 4 5 7 2 10 2];

%Define Cell size
CellGroup = cell(1,6);

%Populate Cells
for i=1:numInputs
    CellGroup{i} = rand(NumRows(i),6); %create a new matrix in each cell. In reality, I am actually doing
                                       %alot of ugly math here, but for simplicity this is similar enough
end

%Generate Outputs
Outputs = FirstFunction(CellGroup)




function [myOutputs] = FirstFunction(myCellGroup) %Reads the input, does more ugly math IRL but simplified
                                                  %here
    myOutputs = zeros(1,length(myCellGroup));
    for j = 1:length(myCellGroup)
        myOutputs(j) = myCellGroup{j}(1,1);
    end
end
```

That being said though, FirstFunction here is being called tens of thousands of times, and so this function takes a considerable amount of time. Is there a 'better' way of doing this? Would it be faster to instead stack these matricies, and then just send an additional matrix that defines the start/stop points? Or are there any other methods I just dont know about to handle these handoffs faster? Or is this just a non-problem due to how fast these handoffs usually are?

Comment: I would recommend you look into how to profile code (`profile on` `profile off` and `profile viewer`). Your question is about function dispatch. My gut instinct, based on many years of experience, is that your approach is the best. I think your problem is elsewhere (thus the profiling recommendation). With MATLAB my experience is there is usually one or two easy fixes, and then a TON of small fixes that you need to make it faster. If you are dynamically allocating memory a lot (not just at the beginning) there are tricks you can use (but if that's the case it is not clear in your example).

Comment: The best format for the data depends on how it’s used, but I think you can’t go wrong with a cell array. Passing that back and forth has exactly the same cost as passing a larger array back and forth. The difference will be in cost of reading the data in those arrays. It is likely that indexing into a larger array is more expensive than fetching an array from a cell array and using that in its entirety.

Comment: Thanks for all the great feedback! I was not sure, since I read online that cells work by sending addresses instead of chunks, which in my mind feels much faster than passing an entire matrix each time, but I know that I know nothing lol

Also: @Jimbo, I will definitely look into code profiling asap! I know I am no software engineer, so I will gladly look into better coding practices. You are correct that other chunks of the code need to be optimized, but the big time sink will be ODE 45 (which is run in the real code during each FirstFunction call), so I am looking into speeding that up too

Comment: In almost all cases, MATLAB passes shared data or reference copies of arguments to functions. That means only new headers are created and there are no deep data copies. This is true whether the variable is a cell array or a large numeric variable ... in both cases there is no deep data copy. Inside the function, however, you can do things that will *cause* a deep data copy (and chew up extra time and memory). As Cris says, using cell array elements in their entirety will be pretty fast, no deep data copy required. But getting a sub-matrix from a larger matrix *will* cause a deep data copy.

Comment: have you tried running FirstFunction without line : myOutputs = zeros(1,length(myCellGroup)) ?

Comment: if the matrices used, the total amount of elements, is larger than the total amount of elements using cells, which is likely, then using cells may save a small amount of time, but it may be really neglectible or even below available resolution. MATLAB indexing of matrices and cells works at same speed. The size of the load makes the difference.